# html_safe with undefined fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-safe

i have a field which is not required i.e. can be nil. i want to use the ffg: myfield.html_safe in my view. this doesn't work for the items that have no myfield. i get an exception, how do i get html_safe to apply only if the field is defined? thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`myfield.html_safe if myfield` or `myfield.to_s.html_safe`

Comment: you'd get an exception here if you try to do nil.to_s

Comment: @Yule not according to the [rubydocs on NilClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/NilClass.html)

Comment: to_s.html_safe seems to work, no exception is thrown. out of curiousity why does converting to_s make a difference? is nil.html_safe not valid?

Comment: the Nil class only has a few basic methods, some of them being the ability to convert to an integer or a string. by using `.to_s`, you are essentially converting `nil` to a String class, and at that point you can use any of the String methods that Rails has added, like `html_safe`.

Answer (score 12):

In Rails, you can use

```
myfield.try(:html_safe)
```

Docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
myfield.html_safe unless myfield.blank?
```